# Why when creating a date, it's created with one day less?

Tags: javascript

I'm creating this date:

```
var myDate = new Date("1949-12-30");
console.log("myDate: " + myDate.toString());
```

The console prints this:

```
Thu Dec 29 1949 19:00:00 GMT-0500 (Hora est. Pacífico, Sudamérica)
```

I need to understand why is that happened.

Comment: The date is being parsed in UTC, but shown in local time zone.

Comment: JavaScript uses UTC as default timezone to parse and store the date. It is displayed in another timezone (according to your browser settings).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is due to timezone conversion. You haven't specified a timezone when you create the date, so it uses UTC. However `toString()` will convert to local timezone, which for you is apparently -0500, which subtracts 5 hours from the date-time, putting it on the previous day 1900 hours.

You can use `toUTCString()` to get the original date:

```
const myDate = new Date("1949-12-30");
console.log("myDate: ", myDate.toUTCString());
```

> myDate:  Fri, 30 Dec 1949 00:00:00 GMT

Comment: Thanks, this answer helped me to understand

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the right date, you just never specified the correct time zone.

If you need to access the date values, you can use `getUTCDate()` or [any of the other getUTC*() functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date):

```js
var d,days;
    d = new Date('2018-02-23');
    days = ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tues', 'Wed', 'Thurs', 'Fri', 'Sat'];
    console.log(days[d.getUTCDay()]);
```

Comment: Thanks, your answer helped me to solve a code problem